# When switching between two activities, show a third view when animating between the two?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a `GridView` which shows images of all the activities in my app.  When the user clicks on one of the `GridView` items, I want to start that activity.  We'll call that started `Activity`, FirstActivity.  Now, when the user clicks on a button in FirstActivity, I want to start a second activity, we'll call it SecondActivity.  However, when transitioning from FirstActivity to SecondActivity, I want to show the GridView between the two.

It would look something like this:

GridActivity (grid item selected) -> FirstActivity
FirstActivity (button click) -> GridActivity -> SecondActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActivityOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html) class to make custom animations on Activity switch. Sadly, it is available only from API v16

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want't it 2.3.3 onwards.

Comment: in this case you can switch to Fragments instead of Activities. You can custom animations to your FragmentTransactions. And this is backwards compatible

Answer (score -1):

You can start a new Activity between the 2, which will be an animation.

This is how i've done it:

In activity1, on button click i call activity2 which is just a view with progressBar and some animation, and which lasts until my acitivity3 is ready to open, then my activity2 starts activity3.

If you just want to have that animation, but you dont have any real loading to do, you can you use threads to simulate some work, for example for 3 seconds, and then call the target activity.